# Dell Poweredge Controller and ZFS

Tags: backup, raid, zfs, raid-5, dell-poweredge

I've been looking at many different option for a home backup server. I'll going to be getting a dell poweredge r430. It contains a perc h730 mini. It has dated hardware, and I plan to pare it with SEAGATE ST1000NM0001 enterprise drives. There seems to be a lot of grey area sounding hw raid vs zfs like in this post: Differences between HW RAID and ZFS (On server fault)

As a person who likes tinkering, and doesn't mind working with command line and other technical bits, which is better at preserving data:

ZFS with the PERC in HBA mode ZFS on top of a hw raid 5 EXT4 on a hw raid 5 or is there something better?

I know offsite secondary backup is the best but is unavailable because I'm cheap, and it will be backups in the event the device fails, not archiving data. I can repair a degraded array in the event of a disk fault, but which system with best protect data from "bit rot" and other more subtle corruptions?

I should add, because the NAS will be backing up many similar devices, and may host some other things such as a plex server, would ZFS be able to take advantage of the powerful ish cpu and 16 gigs of ram? Does the compression it offers make sense? Can it actually compress enough to offset the loss of speed I assume goes with compression?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the speed of hardware RAID, then create a ZFS filesystem on top of the hardware RAID.  If you want to get the full benefit of ZFS, you would add each individual disk into the ZFS pool and create the RAID in software with ZFS.